# Type mismatch error in while using IF and Range code

Tags: excel, vba

Getting a type mismatch error while executing the code.
Here basically i want to copy the rows if the criteria of High or Very High is getting satisfied.

```
Sub Copy()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"

    Set i = Sheets("Risk Assessment")
    Set e = Sheets("High & V High Risk Assessment")
    Dim d
    Dim j As Integer
    d = 4
    j = 5

    Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("Y" & j))
        If i.Range("Y" & j) = "High" Or i.Range("Y" & j) = "Very High" Then
            d = d + 1
            e.Rows(d).Value = i.Rows(j).Value
        End If

        j = j + 1
    Loop

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123"
End Sub
```

Comment: a) In which line does the error occur? b)  I highly recommend to use meaningful variable names. Single letter variable names is a very bad choice. Also probably every programmer will consider `i` as a counter, this is very confusing.

Comment: Variable `i` & `e` are not declare!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Sub Copy()

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"

    Dim i As Worksheet, e As Worksheet
    Dim j As Long, d As Long

    j = 5
    d = 4

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set i = .Worksheets("Risk Assessment")
        Set e = .Worksheets("High & V High Risk Assessment")
    End With

    Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("Y" & j))

        If i.Range("Y" & j) = "High" Or i.Range("Y" & j) = "Very High" Then

            i.Rows(j).EntireRow.Copy e.Rows(d)

            d = d + 1

        End If

        j = j + 1

    Loop

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123"

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry buddy..still getting the same error at 

 If i.Range("Y" & j) = "High" Or i.Range("Y" & j) = "Very High" Then